# Azure DevOps Classic build pipeline always using Windows-Latest Image

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline that I am specifying windows-2019 as the agent specification:
[image: agentSelection]

However whenever the job executes it is using the windows-latest Image
[image: resultingOutput]

Any idea what is going on here and how to solve it?